# Java: Convert a 2d Array of String in a 1d Array of char

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, char

how can I convert a 2d Array of String: `String[][] = {{"A", "-.-"},{"B", "..-"}}` into a array of char: `char[] c = {"A","B"}`?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: 1) Loop through the first dimension of the 2d array; 2) Put at the same index of the second array the result of `charAt(0)` of the first element of the `n`th element of the first array.

Comment: Hello and Welcome! Please share what have you tried and describe your specific issue. If you had no attempt, then use the logic [described by Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996719/java-convert-a-2d-array-of-string-in-a-1d-array-of-char#comment130653787_73996719) and return if you would have a specific problem with your code. Also get familiar with the guide-lines on how to ask questions [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *char[] c = {"A","B"}* Assuming you mean ```char[] c = {'A','B'}``` ? If so, you don't need that array as I'm guessing that required character ```c[n]```  can be obtained with ```char x = (char)('A' + n)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `input` and you create an `output` of the same `.length` as the `input`'s `.length`, then loop an `i` index through the range of 0 ...length - 1 and get the `i`'th record's 0'th record (the letter) and get its first `char` via `charAt(0)`.

```
String[][] input = new String[][] {{"A", "-.-"},{"B", "..-"}};
char[] output = new char[input.length];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output[i] = input[i][0].charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams.

```java
final char[] result = Arrays.stream(input)
                .map(i -> String.valueOf(i[0].charAt(0)))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
                .toCharArray();
```